# Change what vim displays when there is a fold

Tags: vimrc, folding

When I create a fold with `zfap`, vim displays something like:

```
+--  15 lines: myFunctionPrototype :: Test -> Test -> Bool
```

However, I would like vim not to display this number of lines.
I find this distracting, and not adding sufficient information in my case.

I'd prefer:

```
+-- : myFunctionPrototype :: Test -> Test -> Bool
```

or even better:

```
+-- myFunctionPrototype :: Test -> Test -> Bool
```

Is there a way to suppress the line count, or a way to modify what vim displays when there's a fold that I could put in my vimrc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to put in `.vimrc`:

```
set foldtext=MyFoldText()
function MyFoldText()
  let line = getline(v:foldstart)
  let sub = substitute(line, '/\*\|\*/\|{{{\d\=', '', 'g')
  return v:folddashes . sub
endfunction
```

`MyFoldText` is now the function that is responsible for displaying some text, when some lines have been folded.

Comment: `'/\*\|\*/\|{{{\d\='` .... er, excuse me? I didn't quite catch that. The line is terrible. I think you must be speaking over VOIP.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it made me laugh. Well, let's try to filter out noise on your phone line.

Comment: First, some characters has to be escaped, as you probably know it from other languages than VIMScript, which I plan to learn soon, but I have pushback that idea until the last possible moment :-)

Comment: "/\*" is short for the C++ begin comment /*   the start is \* ; and similarily "\*/" is for end comment

Comment: "{{{" is used by vim as a marker so as to fold text

Comment: and now diving in the details, I see that I no longer understand the code, and start hear myself speaking over VOIP. I'm gonna check vim :help and see if I can remember what this means.

Answer (score 2):

The text that is displayed for a closed fold is determined by the `'foldtext'` option. See

```
:help 'foldtext'
:help fold-foldtext
```

The latter topic has a few examples of ways to get different text. As another, simple example,

```
:set foldtext=v:folddashes
```

will result in a line of only dashes (actually hyphens) across the full width of the window.

Comment: not accros the full width of the window. I only have one dash at the start. but thanks, that's where I have to look at.

Comment: Yes, across the full width of the window. Example: `vim -N -u NONE -c "set foldtext=v:folddashes" -c "put=''" -c "normal ggzfG"`